# how delete an element from 2d list with Iterating with two loops in java

Tags: java, python

i am working on converting a python code to java, right now i want to remove elements from a 2d List with two loops. here is the python code;

```py
    for index1 in reversed(range(test_num)):
        for item in rm_list:
            #print(covMatrix_int[index1][item])
            del covMatrix_int[index1][item]
```

now in java i am doing that like this:

```java
    for(int index3=TestNum-1; index3 >=0; index3-- ) {
                //System.out.print(index3);
                for(Integer item: RmList) {
                    //System.out.println(CovMatrixInt.get(index3).get(item));

                    CovMatrixInt.get(index3).remove(item); ///ERROR
                }
            }
```

when i am printing `covMatrix_int[index1][item]` and `CovMatrixInt.get(index3).get(item)` the results for both are same but in java it is not deleting all the elements which i want to delete.

Comment: what does recursion have to do with this?

Comment: Alnitak i am a learner maybe it does not have recursion, but it have two loops and i want to delete all the elements at those indexes by those two loops

Comment: What happens if instead of `remove(item)` you write `remove(item.intValue())`?

Comment: In your second loop, you declare an Integer => no need, just use int :) And what is the type of covMatrix ?

Comment: RealSkeptic i think your trick worked... you can share it as an answer for this question.

Comment: ko2r i have tried that. and type of covmatrix is ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArrayList, refer below if it helps

By using remove() methods :
ArrayList provides two overloaded remove() method.

1. remove(int index) : Accept index of object to be removed.
2. remove(Obejct obj) : Accept object to be removed.

```
yourList.remove(index3);

OR

yourList.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

as Suggested by RealSkeptic i changed remove(item) to remove(item.intValue()) thats worked.

```
for(int index3=TestNum-1; index3 >=0; index3-- ) {
                //System.out.print(index3);
                for(Integer item: RmList) {
                    //System.out.println(CovMatrixInt.get(index3).get(item));

                    CovMatrixInt.get(index3).remove(item.intValue()); ///ERROR
                }
            }
```